# Can a single HDMI port be used for two external displays?

Tags: laptop, hdmi

Is it posssible to connect two external monitors using a single HDMI port, perhaps using a special adapter/splitter?

The two displays are currently connected to a desktop using VGA and DVI.

Comment: If your DVI is DVI-D, it can run dual displays. But if your computer has both HDMI and DVI ports, this is a great way to get two separate monitors.

Comment: All I have is a HDMI port on my laptop. I wanted to replace my desktop at work with this laptop and still use my dual screens. I guess this won't happen.

Comment: Ah, you can look into getting a docking station, but yeah, laptop graphics cards aren't as awesome as most desktop ones.

Comment: Answer from 2014 which says it is not possible: https://superuser.com/questions/805983/can-i-connect-two-monitors-to-my-computer-using-an-hdmi-splitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to with an HDMI splitter.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an HDMI Splitter and your computer will output to that splitter.

Your computer won't know the 2nd monitor exists. So as a result, you won't be able to make dual monitors out of it. Instead the 2 monitors will be a mirror display of each other.

Comment: Which means that it is pretty useless ;-) Thanks for the info!

Comment: Right, but the other way around could be helpful- if you have multiple PCs and a [KVM switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch).

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop has a Type-C connector, you can look up its capabilities on the manufacturer's website. If it has Displayport capability, you can use USB-C to Display Port, and if your monitor doesn't support Display Port, you can use an adapter, although it's possible that it won't work.

It is not possible to connect multiple monitors to a single HDMI port.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to spare some change then expensive specialty solutions are available:

- The Matrox QuadHead2Go Q155 Multi-Monitor Controller can power 4 screens using a single HDMI out from your PC to 4 monitors.

  Source: https://www.matrox.com/en/video/products/video-walls/quadhead2go-series/q155-appliance

  Price: around 1500 USD.
- I am sure you might find comparable knock-offs under the search term "TV wall processors HDMI", which claim to do similar things but in reality probably just split a single large screen into 4 parts send to different monitors e.g. [https://www.amazon.com/-/de/dp/B08DV11VC2/ref=pd_lpo_4?pd_rd_i=B08DV11VC2&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08DV11VC2)

To get back to your original question:

- The HDMI Spec does not contain any provisions for carry multiple monitors signals or daisy chaining.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using an [HDMI splitter](https://www.google.com/search?q=HDMI+splitter), but it will only have one source (aka one display, not extended display).

Comment: Ok so the two monitors will actually display the exact same thing, without the ability to extend the desktop?

Comment: Correct, all the device is doing it making two copies of the video for two wires, you will not be able to make the screen's show different things.