# Can I connect two monitors to my computer using an hdmi splitter

Tags: hdmi

Can I connect two monitors to my computer using an HDMI splitter because my computer only has one HDMI output that works which is coming from the Graphics Card. Both monitors are the excact same and I wanted to go extended mode with them.

Comment: If by slitter you mean a simple cable then no. If you mean something like video wall slitter - than yes ( it is essentially like having an external video card to do the "split" operation..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

HDMI splitters just duplicate the screen (so you'll get two screens showing the exact same thing). If you want to extend your desktop (ie, have both monitors either show up individually on your computer, or have your computer output to a double width screen which the HDMI splitter then splits and displays on half of each additional screen) you'll be facing a lot more problems.

Better off just getting a dual output graphics card, or getting something that supports display port 1.2 (which lets you just chain monitors that also support 1.2 display port daisy chaining all from a single display port outout).

Ref: I'm currently working on a computer with four monitors, all showing up as individual monitors, connected to a single displayport output from my graphics card.

Comment: I found out that I have an HDMI port and a DVI port on my monitor. Could I have one port screen use DVI and the other use HDMI? They are both the exact same screen.

Comment: PLease note that both of my monitors have an HDMI, DVI, and AVG port.

Comment: What ports do you have coming out of your graphics card? If you have a DVI and a HDMI then yes, plug your monitors in one via HDMI and the other via DVI. Both are digital standards and should look the same quality. VGA (I assume that's what you meant by AVG) is an older analogue standard and you should avoid using it if possible. Note, there are some DVI to HDMI adaptors you can get, but honestly, if your PC and monitor both have DVI connectors, just use a DVI cable.

Comment: Oh, and yes, most likely if you do this your computer will then show two monitors attached and you can extend your desktop onto the second monitor and you will end up with two independent screens available in windows.

Comment: My graphics card has a DVI port and an HDMI port. Since my monitors both came with a DVI cable but not an HDMI one, I buy an HDMI cable, connect it to my main monitor, and use the exisiting DVI cable to connect my 2nd monitor. Thanks!

Comment: Some graphics cards will support passive DisplayPort converters, and even the DisplayPort protocol (allowing you to use an adapter on your DVI port, and then daisy chaining your monitors together).  But don't count on it; if you have a friend with the cables who will let you borrow them, try it out first and make sure it works before committing any money.  A new graphics card is probably cheaper.  (Because, likely, your monitors don't support display port daisy chaining anyway.)

Answer (score -2):

It's not possible to send both audio and video to each individual monitor that you have unless as stated by the first response you would need a graphic card with two HDMI outputs.

Just have one designated for HDMI and DVI for the second monitor. And run the audio from your external speakers or from the laptop or something. Remember, the HDMI and DVI are the same just an exception of one that doesn't have the audio which is DVI.